# load value to a textbox dynamically

Tags: jsp

Sir, I've a combobox whose id is "courseid" in my jsp page removeCourse.jsp. When i change the value of the combobox i want the corresponding coursename will be displayed in a textbox whose id is cname. For this purpose i've make a servlet which returns the corresponding result with a resultset rs. I write the code as below
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/online_exam?"+"user=root&password=pass");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

```
        courseid=request.getParameter("courseid");
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select course_name from course where course_id='"+courseid+"'");
        setCourseName s=new setCourseName();
        s.setCourseName(cname);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            cname=rs.getNString("course_name");
            s.setCourseName(cname);

        }
        //response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/ONLINEEXAMINATION/removeCourse2.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("courseName",cname);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("http://localhost:8080/ONLINEEXAMINATION/removeCourse.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and then in the jsp page i write the code to assign the value as given below

But  it doesn't display the coursename in the textbox when i select a courseid from the combobox. Can you say where is the problem? In the web.xml i also write the following

        searchCname
        /removeCourse

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`request.getRequestDispatcher("http://localhost:8080/ONLINEEXAMINATION/removeCourse.jsp").forward(request, response);`

you have to change the path to

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/removeCourse.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

The url you are providing is wrong.

Comment: I had treid by writing your answer also. But still it is not working

Comment: how can i handle the onchange event of the combobox in this case

Comment: You just have to display the name in the textbox, than forwarding the whole request is a bad idea. \nInstaed of that you can fire a Ajax call and on the onChange event of combobox and when the rersponse comes you can set the value in the textbox using **document.getElementById(textBoxId).value.

Comment: how can i fire an ajax on the onchange event, can you please give an example.